# json being converted into BSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

i am using sails js framework for node.

I would like to ask why my json from mongodb is being converted to bson.
And then I queried/retrieved using sails model/Waterline ORM. And I got a BSON.

is there anyway I can convert BSON to JSON? Why am I getting a BSON instead of a JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `.toJSON` function. Duh.

```
User.find().exec(
  function(err,myRecord){
    var datUser = myRecord.pop().toJSON();
    console.log(datUser);
  })
```

Or use the `.toObject()` to strip all instance methods as well.

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-object